# B2C Custom Impersonation Policy Giving Error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create a custom policy that allows a user to impersonate another user.  It is based off the impersonation sample (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/impersonation) and uses the starter pack.

However I didn't want social accounts so I used the LocalAccounts starter pack and modified the policy.  It brings up the login screen but then does not bring up the second screen and instead returns a generic error (ServerError: AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.)

Can anyone help me get this policy working or point out the problem in it?

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="mytenantdev.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_Impersonation" PublicPolicyUri="http://mytenantdev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Impersonation" TenantObjectId="b21d8c41-8fdb-4f82-835d-2c1765fcc855">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>mytenantdev.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Sample: targetEmail is the email of the user originally requested impersonatedUser is the 
       email value returned from SignInNames.Email from Azure AD after we requested (this is directory data) -->
      <ClaimType Id="targetEmail">
        <DisplayName>Sign-in on behalf of</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Email address of the impersonated user</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>EmailBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="impersonatedUser">
        <DisplayName>Impersonated account</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText />
      </ClaimType>
      <!--Sample: Indicates whether a user can impersonate (if the value is 1)-->
      <ClaimType Id="extension_can_impersonate">
        <DisplayName>Can impersonate</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Add help text here</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <!--Sample: Stores the error message if user can't impersonate-->
      <ClaimType Id="errorMessage">
        <DisplayName>Error</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Add help text here</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>

    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <!--Sample: Initiates the errorMessage claims type with the error message-->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUnsolicitedErrorMessage" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="You are not allow to impersonate. Please content your administrator" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <!--Sample: this technical profile provides input for targetEmail and runs validation technical 
      profile for to read the impersonated user profile -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted Targeted Email Exchange</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-TargetEmailExchange">
          <DisplayName>Target Email Page</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <!--Sample:  indicating that claim resolving should be performed. So, we can read the value of {OAUTH-KV:targetEmail} claim resolver -->
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: read the targetEmail query string parameter e.g. &targetemail=bob@contoso.com -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="targetEmail" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:targetEmail}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="impersonatedUser" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="targetEmail" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ImpersonatedUserRead" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Sample: Show error message if user is not allowed to impersonate-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ErrorMessage">
          <DisplayName>Error message</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <!-- Sample: Remove the continue button-->
            <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUnsolicitedErrorMessage" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Sample: read the extension_can_impersonate attribute-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_can_impersonate" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!--Sample: Read target user and return error it doesn't exist. 
        If exists, pipes value into impersonatedUser claim type -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ImpersonatedUserRead">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Look up in the signInNames to see if the value in targetEmail contains - look it up-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="targetEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Sample: Returns the value in targetEmail and check in signInNames collection, then 
                 returns value in SignInName and pipe into impersonatedUser-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="impersonatedUser" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="Impersonation">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!--Sample: Sign-in with your own credentials or select to sign-in with social account  -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!--Sample: Sign-in with social account, or create new local account -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        
        <!--Sample: this step reads your own account properties-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Sample: Check whether user can impersonate -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_can_impersonate</Value>
              <Value>1</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-ErrorMessage" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ErrorMessage" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!--Sample: Collect the email address of the end user of act of behalf of-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TargetEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-TargetEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!--Sample: Issu an access token-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="Impersonation" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <!--        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/> -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="impersonatedUser" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <!--      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" /> -->
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="oid" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Have you enabled extension attribute support? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#modify-your-custom-policy

Comment: Use https://aka.ms/iefsetup next time, it automates the setup to make it compatible with pretty much all the samples

Answer (score 2):

just in case it saves time to someone, I have had exactly the same problem with changing the custom impersonate policy template provided by microsoft. It is very important to name the attribute correctly:

- in the azure portal, simply call the custom attribute:

  **can_impersonate**
- in the impersonate custom policy XML file, reference this custom
  attribute with the `extension` prefix as:
  **extension_can_impersonate**
- in the Microsoft Graph API, when updating this attribute to 1,
  reference it as :

  **extension_{b2c-extensions-app ApplicationClientID
  without hyphens}_can_impersonate**

set the custom attribute to 1

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenant](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/%7Btenant) name}.onmicrosoft.com/users/33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333

```json
{
    "extension_44444444444444444444444444444444_can_impersonate": "1" }
```

define to override the `AAD-Common` TechnicalProfile in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file (overriding the corresponding TechnicalProfile definition from the TrustFrameworkBase.xml file):

```xml
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ID here, for example: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-->  
            <Item Key="ClientId">{real b2c-extensions-app application ID here}</Item>
            <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId here, for example: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222-->
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{real b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId here}</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles> 
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

when this is set correctly - the user impersonation using a custom policy in the Azure AD B2C works like a charm!